# Xcode Storyboard appears empty

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I updated Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7. I open a project made with 6.4 and I find the main storyboard completely empty, like in the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y92K0.jpg

In the left pane I can see all the objects for the View Controller, but I can't select anything from the right view. If I open the storyboard as source code, I can see everything.

I tried before and after converting the code to Swift 2, with no difference.

How can I fix this to view all objects in the view controller?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Same here - I get 10 rows of cells, then the storyboard is empty.

Comment: What a great feature. Thanks, Steve!

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that works for me is the as often the most obvious one (not for a lack of trying alternatives which include the words uninstall and re-install and purge):

> Temporarily adjust the size of your View Controller (typically the
>   height is the culprit) from (Inferred) to Freeform till every
>   component of your document is theoretically visible.

Then all your components will be visible, editable, selectable...
Proceed with your edits, save and switch it back to what it was before.
All changes will get retained, the project will build & render fine.

It's an annoying additional step, but at least I could regain the ability to work on my project files.

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue, and I stumbled on your question. I tried your solution and it works, however when I put it back to how it was before, the elements go invisible again. Do you know if there's a permanent and beautiful solution?

Comment: No, I don't. But at least you can edit your UI conveniently in IB.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ever have a problem before Xcode 7.1?

Comment: No, not really (aside some hiccups here and there as widely reported). But this is really an anomaly and mention worthy bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same issue as you and what I am about to tell you will probably not make you very happy. **This solution still applies if you haven't or are not planning on downloading the latest Xcode 7.3 beta released on January 25th 2016. If you are going to, scroll down.**

On my end, I tried everything: uninstalling, reinstalling, etc. etc.

I ended up accepting that the only way to get our invisible labels and elements back is to run our projects on Xcode 7.0.1. It's very counter-productive, but it's literally the only way I could find of working without removing more hair out.

If you want to try it out, here's what I did:

1. Download Xcode 7.0.1 from the Developer Downloads page.
2. Then, open the DMG and copy the file to your Desktop.
3. Rename the file to "Xcode-7.0.1" and move it to your Applications folder.
4. OSX might start verifying the application upon launch, so accept whatever it says about "The application has been downloaded on the Internet. Do you want to launch it?"
5. Open your project and voila.
6. Do whatever modifications you need, save, and quit this version of Xcode.

The following steps are only to be done if really needed, but they are overall optional steps.

7. Open the latest version of Xcode (at this time, 7.1 build 7B91b).
8. Build and package the app for App Store submission.

Voila.

This is most likely some bug in Xcode. Hopefully it will be corrected in Xcode 7.2.

Should anyone have a better solution, please, feel free to let us know!

**Update-- using Xcode 7.3 beta 2 (7D129n)**

So I was wrong, Apple didn't fix this in 7.2. However, they fixed this issue in the latest Xcode 7.3 beta 2 (7D129n) that was released two days ago (on January 25th 2016 to be exact).

I just tried it out and it actually is fixed. Let's hope nothing will change that though!

Comment: thanks a lot! i will try this solution soon... btw i have other similar projects that don't have this issue. Only one particular project has been corrupted

Comment: Yeah it's a hit and miss in most cases. My teammates have zero issues, whilst I have the same problem on both my rMBP and iMac. I'm almost positive it's a corrupted installation but I'm not exactly ready to wipe my machines to check it out. Let me know how it goes for you!

Comment: I wiped to check. it's not a corrupted installation unless they make sure to always tie this corrupted version to your Apple ID.

Comment: I just changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. Fortunately, my project was source controlled. I was able to compare the storyboard with the one in the repo (in the source code mode). The height of the views seems to have changed to 600, though I had not made any changes. The height of all views was set to 600.

Reverting back to the repo version solved my problem. For those who don't have source control, this may not be of much use. But just want to let you know that the issue is just with the storyboard file and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Not showing in IB / greyed out in organizer usually means that those views are not applicable to the currently displayed size class. Perhaps you added them to a more specific size class but are now looking at any / any.

Try to change the sizeclass to something more specific and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I closed Xcode and reopened the project and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had also have the same problem and solved it with following way.....

**Storyboard -> Attribute inspector -> simulator size -> Fixed**